# JQuery .load and html issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use Javascript to load different pages when you press a link. Here is the function I am using to change the page.

```
function loadPage(url){
    $(".body").fadeOut(400, function(){
        $(".body").load(url, function(){
            $(".body").fadeIn(400);
        });
    });
};
```

The problem is, it fades the stuff into the page, but it disappears once the fadeIn is done. The code html from the file is still in the main files html, it just doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue, and I used this.  File in your case would be the url:

```
var loader = function(file) {

   $('.body').fadeOut(500);

 $.ajax({ 
     url: file

     success: function(data) {

        $('.body').html(data);

$('.body').fadeIn(500);

  }

 });


  }
```

Changed the code to try and match what your looking to do, tested it with just a div with a background and it seems to work okay.

Is this the same as what you have ?

Andrew

Comment: Will this work as well if I click a button and call the function?

Comment: If can do, you need to take the var's required with it.  I use that on a menu which are buttons, but made with divs rather than an actual button

Comment: Worth noting, I am using a opacity sheet z-index: 9999 and a loading gif while the change takes place, you can remove those bits :)

Comment: Ok, I modified the code you posted to this

`function loadPage(file){
     $.ajax({ 
         url: file,
         timeout: 20000,

         success: function(data) {
            $('.body').html(data);
        }
    });
}`

and it still didnt work. Cant get the code formatted :( Whats weird is, both my code and yours works when the page first loads, but when I click a button it doesn't.

Comment: I have changed the code above in my answer to try and match yours.  Is this what you have ?

Comment: Mostly, yes. But the code above doesn't seem to be working for me. It loads the file, but the code still is hidden, its in the source code though.